# How to check a lua-table if a key is present?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Every minute I retrieve the following data from a webshop via a request.

```
  {
  ['action'] = 'all',
  ['orders'] = { ['order'] = { [1] = { ['locationId'] = 1,
                                       ['id'] = 93,
                                       ['orderNumber'] = '3200'
                                     }
                             }
               },
  ['status'] = 'success'
  }
```

From this table I need the ID number which I read with the code:

`IdNummer = Table.orders.order[1].id;`

If there is an order, this works

If no order is ready, I will receive the following table:

```
{ 
['action'] = 'all', 
['orders'] = { ['order'] = {}  }, 
['status'] = 'success'
}
```

Since "id" doesn't exist, I get the error: Attempt to index a nil value (field'?') 
How can I check if "id" exists without getting an error?

Comment: `(Table.orders.order[1] or {}).id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first check that the entry `Table.orders.order[1]` exists before trying to access it's `id` field.

In lua an unassigned field has the `nil` value. So you can do:

```
local orders = Table.orders.order
local IdNummer = nil
if orders[1] ~= nil then
  IdNummer = orders[1].id;
end
```

Take care, in this example if the index doesn't exists `IdNummer` will have a nil value.